# Segfault on strtok in C

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

```
typedef struct S_Linear_Chain *Chain;

struct S_Linear_Chain
{
    char mot[20];
    int occ;
    Chain next;
};
```

I'm coding a string chain list and I need to tokenize my text.
All my function work individually but in `construire_list()` function I get a segfault.
I think it's because my str is constant. 
    Chain new_Chain() { return NULL; }

```
Chain insereDebut(Chain deb,char* c)
{
    Chain new = malloc(sizeof(struct S_Linear_Chain));
    strcpy(new->mot,c);
    new->next = deb;
    new->occ++;
    return new;
}

Chain construire_list()
{
    char s1[MAX];
    Chain l = new_Chain();
    fgets(s1, MAX, stdin);
    char * s = strdup(s1);
    const char * separators = " ";
    char * strToken = strtok (s, separators );
    while ( strToken != NULL ) {
        insereDebut(l,strToken);

      }


    return l;
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: (a) Provide a [mcve]. (b) When `new->occ++;` is executed in `insereDebut`, `new->occ` has not been assigned a value.

Comment: You are only calling strtok once. You need to call it for each token. More importantly you need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: regarding: `char * s = strdup(s1);`  Since the array pointer `s1` is not set to point to a valid string, the call to `strdup()` will stop duplicating the char array pointer to by `s1`.  Where will `strdup()` encounter a NUL byte?  No one really knows.  The result is undefined behavior.  Please correct

Comment: regarding: `while ( strToken != NULL ) {
        insereDebut(l,strToken); }`  this fails to update `strToken` so will always point to the same part of the string.  Suggest:  `while ( strToken != NULL ) {
        insereDebut(l,strToken); strToken = strtok (NULL, separators ); }`

Answer (score 2):

> I think it's because my str is constant.

Why would you think that? Your str is *not* constant: it's right here:

```
char * s = strdup(s1);
```

There are many bugs in your is code (it's actually fascinating that so many bugs could be counted in so few lines of code).

1. The call to `strdup` is unnecessary: you could just as easily tokenize `s1`.
2. The memory returned by `strdup` is leaked.
3. The call to `strtok` will find the *first* token. The rest of the line will remain untokenized (you must call `strtok` repeatedly to tokenize the entire line).
4. You should remove trailing `\n` that `fgets` will read.
5. Since `strToken` is never updated, your `while` loop will run forever, until you exhaust all memory (which is likely the cause of your crash).
6. Since you ignore the return value of `insereDebut`, you leak memory here as well. The code should most likely be: `l = insereDebut(l,strToken);`
7. In `insereDebut`, this line: `new->occ++;` increments uninitialized value (the initial value of `new->occ` is undefined).

Please learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I correct all the point but i always get a segfault .. please see my answer below

Comment: @ZouitineMehdi You didn't correct *all* points (e.g. newline handling is still missing).  Instead of providing an "answer", you should edit your question, and provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve